# Using a second screen but Kubuntu asks me to choose what to show on the screen but the screen says "no signal"

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Just as the title says... I am connecting the screen via HDMI cable and kubuntu asks me wheter I want to mirror my main screen or extend to the right or left and so on and no matter what I choose the screen gets no signal. The wierd thing is, that if I disconnect the HDMI cable kubuntu also asks me what I want the second screen to show.